# How to translate geometric intuitions about vector fields into algebraic equations

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology, vector-fields

By considering stereographic projections, I was asked to find a smooth vector field on $S^2$ which vanishes at 1 point, and one that vanishes at 2 points. The intuition, I think, for the vanishing at 1 point is to have all vectors emanating from either the north pole or south pole; for the vanishing at 2 points I think it should be swirling around one of the axes. But I don't know which fields in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will get mapped to these under the push forward of the coordinate maps. Whats the approach to figuring this out?

Comment: You need more than intuition, you need to write down actual formulas. So for example, imagine a vector field "swirling around one of the axes", and then figure out how to write down a formula for a vector field which does that (and is tangent to $S^2$).

Comment: If i were to use $(u,v)$ coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then would the push forward under coordinate chart of $v\frac{\partial}{\partial u}-u\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ be a smooth vector field on $S^2$ vanishing at precisely 2 points?

Comment: That's the right idea, but it does not quite work because stereographic projection leaves out a single point on $S^2$; you must take care to ensure that the vector field extends continuously to the missing point.

Comment: My own take on this is that stereographic projection is just a red herring. To me it would make more sense to define a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose value at each point of $S^2$ is tangent to $S^2$.

Comment: I believe Poincare-Hopf rules out your intuition for a vector field vanishing at just one point. For inspiration look up a picture of a dipole.

Answer (score 1):

First, to address the question in your title: I think the only honest answer is that there is no "standard algorithm" for translating intuitions into equations. It takes lots of practice and lots of trial and error. Try to stretch your geometric intuition as far as you can, and then try to write down formulas to prove your intuition correct. The things that hang you up will lead to new insights, which you can feed back into your intuition for the next pass.

Lee Mosher is probably right that stereographic projection is a red herring for the problem of finding a vector field that vanishes at exactly two points -- there are simpler ways to write down such a vector field, such as the one tangent to latitude circles. But to find a vector field that vanishes at exactly one point, stereographic projection can be extremely helpful.  [Hint: think about a coordinate vector field on $\mathbb R^2$.]

Comment: (Not OP but) I would settle for "how do I write down vector fields", full stop. Without using the identification $T_pS^2\cong \{x\in\Bbb R^3: x\cdot p=0\}$ (which, even this is hoodwinking an embedding of $S^2\subseteq\Bbb R^3$) I don't know a way to do this which isn't exceedingly painful even in such a simple case.